# Ubuntu SED: Replacing with regular expressions

Tags: regex, replace, sed

I want to replace a text from an input file. The input file contains following input text:

```
...
[
%% Riak Client APIs config
{riak_api, [
        %% pb_backlog is the maximum length to which the queue of pending
        %% connections may grow. If set, it must be an integer >= 0.
        %% By default the value is 5. If you anticipate a huge number of
        %% connections being initialised *simultaneously*, set this number
        %% higher.
        %% {pb_backlog, 64},

        %% pb is a list of IP addresses and TCP ports that the Riak
        %% Protocol Buffers interface will bind.
        {pb, [ {"192.168.75.999", 8087 } ]}
        ]},

%% Riak Core config
...
```

I tried to enter the following SED regex expression:

```
sed -i -e "s/\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}\", 8087/$my_ip\", 8087" /path/to/file
```

As a result I want to have the old IP address 192.168.58.999 replaced with the server's actual IP address. The "my_ip" variable is filed with the server's IP value from a former step. SED executes the regex expression and returns without error, but also without any changes to the file.

I would appreciate any help regarding this issue. (I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.2, 64 bit)

Comment: Might be easier if we could see the input.  Just a few lines if it is long.

Comment: Well, you're missing a backslash before the first `d`... would that help?

Comment: If you want to `replace a text from an input file` then show us `a text from an input file` so we can help you.

Comment: Hi guys you're absolutely right. Here are some more lines from the input file. The backslash was already in the regex expression. I corrected it right now in this text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I managed to solve the problem. With the following SED code snippet it worked for me.

```
sed -ire "s/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\"\, 8087/$my_ip \"\, 8087/g"
```

Answer (score 1):

does this help?

```
kent$ my_ip="newIpAddr"

kent$ sed "s/\".*\"/\"$my_ip\"/" <<< '{pb, [ {"192.168.58.999", 8087 } ]}'
{pb, [ {"newIpAddr", 8087 } ]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a backslash for the first `\d`, but that's moot since sed doesn't understand `\d` anyways.

```
sed -ire "s/[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}\", 8087/$my_ip\", 8087/" /path/to/file
```

Changes:

- Added `-r` flag to enable extended regexes. Needed for the curly braces.
- Use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`.
- Escape `.` with `\.` so it matches periods rather than *any character*.
- `\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}` shortened to `(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}`.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for the answer. Anyway it didn't help out. Am I missing something else?